# Feature Deployment with more than 1 server

Tags: deployment, feature

When you have a SharePoint farm with more than 1 server. If deploying a feature what servers do you need to run it on. Does the power shell commands you use change?

For example in my farm I have a DB server, Central Admin Server, Search Server and two Front End Web Servers. What Servers would I deploy my features on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy it on any server in the farm that is running SharePoint and it will deploy to all servers in the farm.  The same powershell commands are used in either case.

Comment: To clarify, you would run `Add-SPSolution` or `Update-SPSolution` on your Central Admin Server (I guess front end would work too).